# Evaluate command based on variable at bash

Tags: bash, variable, openvpn, syntax

I am writing a small script that would choose random file for me from the directory and execute command with this chosen filename as a parameter.

It is about choosing random `.ovpn` file and run `sudo openvpn path_to_filename`

```
Here is my script:
#!/bin/bash
allFilesInDirectory=(/etc/openvpn/*)
echo ${#allFilesInDirectory[@]}
randomNumber=$[RANDOM % ${#allFilesInDirectory[@]}]
echo $randomNumber
echo ${allFilesInDirectory[randomNumber]}
choosenFile=${allFilesinDirectory[randomNumber]}
echo $choosenFile
echo "CHOOSEN: ${choosenFile} AS A RANDOM WITH NUMBER ${randomNumber} OF ${#allFilesInDirectory[@]} "
echo ""
EXECUTE COMMAND HERE
```

First of all at the echo starting with CHOOSEN there is no path displayed (so no content of choosenFile variable is passed), but a randomNumber variable content is displayed! I tried to play with ' " \ and some other syntaxes with no success.

The more important is that execution of my command doesn't see the content of variable choosenFile too! I tried to do for few ways too. Like for example

```
command="sudo openvpn ${choosenFile}"
eval $command

"sudo openvpn ${choosenFIle}"

"sudo openvpn \${choosenFIle}"

"sudo openvpn $choosenFIle"
```

and at best I got openvpn help output, so no content of variable choosenFile was passed.

May someone point my lack of knowledge? I just started with bash scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the variable name.

This:

```
choosenFile=${allFilesinDirectory[randomNumber]}
```

Should be:

```
choosenFile=${allFilesInDirectory[randomNumber]}
```

Actually, for good practice you should double-quote your variables when you use them. This is so that spaces in the values don't get evaluated by the shell when you least expect it. So the correct line should be this:

```
choosenFile="${allFilesInDirectory[randomNumber]}"
```

I would *strongly* recommend you use https://www.shellcheck.net/ for checking your shell scripts. As it happens it would have picked up your typo and warned you about it.

As for the second part of your question, just stop double-quoting the entire line. Write the command and reference the variable where you need it, for example like this:

```
sudo openvpn "$choosenFile"
```

Comment: Thank a lot! That is wonderful. And one more time thanks you for the link and double-qoute hint. Have a nice day !